# Verify protobuf message definition

Tags: protocol-buffers

Is it possible to get a hash of the protobuf message definition? The hash should be on the **message definition itself**, not depending on any data that's in it. I'm using protobuf to transfer data across machines, and I want to make sure they are compiled against the exactly same definition of **message structure**.

Comment: I'm sure you could write something like that (have you seen https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#self-description ?), but I'm curious about your use case - is this not something you could handle with the built-in compatibility features (e.g. as described in https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto?hl=en#updating)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the message descriptor using `google::protobuf::Message::GetDescriptor()` interface. Using the `Descriptor::CopyTo()` method you can then convert this to `DescriptorProto`, which contains all the information about the protobuf message stored itself in protobuf format. This you can then serialize and hash in whatever way you want.

But I agree with whrrgarbl's comment that protobuf already has very good forwards- and backwards-compatibility. So unless you have very special reasons this hashing seems unnecessary and will only make future maintenance of your code more difficult.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question. In fact, even though protobuf has some good compatibility, I want to *strictly* use the same version of definition, or throw an exception at very first.